# How to auto populate value from properties file using groovy script on Jenkins Active Choices Reactive Parameter

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I am currently using Active Choices Parameter and Reactive Parameter in Jenkins and I was able to populate the value in Reactive parameter from Properties file using this script.

Active Choices Reactive Parameter
Groovy Script:

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
File propertiesFile = new File ('Properties file Path')
propertiesFile.withInputStream {
properties.load(it)
}
if (ACP.equals('Test1')){
def array = properties.test1.split(',')
return [array[0],array[1],array[3]]
}
```

Every time I added new value to properties file I also need to add additional array(array[4]) to the script.
I there any way to automatically populate the array depending on how many values in the properties file?

I tried this and it doesn't work.

```
def array = properties.getProperties(test1).split(',')

return array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way using this script:

```
def options = []
array.each { key ->
options.add(key)
}
return options
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).